# call ddev-project by browser and url on foreign machine in local network

Tags: ubuntu, https, server, local, ddev

I have a local network running (192.168.178.xxx) and I want to use ddev on a local server (192.168.178.80, Ubuntu 20.x server). This server is accessible local by IP or SSH.

There is a small docker-project running on 192.168.178.80:1000. At this place, there is no need for acecssing by url.

After starting a different ddev-project on 192.168.178.80, which runs perfect, it says:

> Successfully started projectname
>
> Project can be reached at https://projectname.ddev.site https://127.0.0.1:12345

How can I access it by using https://projectname.ddev.site inside the local network? Is this possible without editing each clients /etc/hosts-file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "projectname.ddev.site" as is, you'll have to run your own DNS server in your local network, because "projectname.ddev.site" always evaluates to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) when using regular DNS.

You can use any other project FQDN if you want, again you'll have to either run a local DNS (or DNS somewhere else) or you'll have to edit /etc/hosts.

You'll probably be interested in these links:

- https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/details/alternate-uses/ which explains how to run a server on the internet
- https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/topics/sharing/ explains how to share your site on a local network.